# Google forms multiple "isblank" on a nested if instance

Tags: function, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Can anybody suggest on how could i shorten this function? It is working well but I find hard to manage if in case I would add more cells. Thank you!

```
=if(AND(ISBLANK(E13),ISBLANK(E14),ISBLANK(E15)),"3",
if(AND(ISBLANK(E13),ISBLANK(E14),NOT(ISBLANK(E15))),"2",
if(AND(ISBLANK(E13),ISBLANK(E15),NOT(ISBLANK(E14))),"2",
if(AND(ISBLANK(E14),ISBLANK(E15),NOT(ISBLANK(E13))),"2",
if(AND(NOT(ISBLANK(E14:E15)),ISBLANK(E13)),"1",
if(AND(NOT(ISBLANK(E13:E14)),ISBLANK(E15)),"1",
if(AND(NOT(ISBLANK(E13:E15)),ISBLANK(E14)),"1","No Available Units")))))))
```

[image: google sheets reference]

Comment: (at the last line) the range in `ISBLANK(E13:E15)` already includes cell `E14` .. right?